# Remove Cancel button from PyQt4 Progress Dialog

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt4, progressdialog

I have the following progress bar and it pops up with a Cancel button. I wish to remove it as I have no purpose for it. This progressDialogue() is part of a larger class.

```
def progressDialogue(self, value):
    '''
    :param value [int]: Value on progress bar
    :return: Progress bar dialogue box
    '''
    self.prog = QtGui.QProgressDialog()
    self.prog.setWindowTitle('Please wait...')
    self.prog.setGeometry(500,300,500,100)
    self.prog.setMinimum(0)
    self.prog.setMaximum(100)
    self.prog.show()
    self.prog.setValue(value)
    if value == 100:
        self.prog.hide()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cancel button can be customised using [setCancelButton](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qprogressdialog.html#setCancelButton):

```
    self.prog.setCancelButton(None)
```